# How can I create 2 new columns, one that looks up a prior match and one that show the next match

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataset that looks similar to the below and would like to create two new columns. One column would return the prior year, and if 0 return NAN. The Second column would return the Next year, and if none, add 4 to the year.

data table:

| NAME | YEAR | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | 2012 | 0 |
| Foo | 2017 | 1 |
| Foo | 2022 | 2 |
| Bar | 2015 | 0 |
| Bar | 2014 | 2 |

Goal Results:

| Name | Year | Count | Prior | Next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | 2012 | 0 | NAN | 2017 |
| Foo | 2017 | 1 | 2012 | 2022 |
| Foo | 2022 | 2 | 2017 | 2026 |
| Baa | 2015 | 0 | NAN | 2024 |
| Baa | 2024 | 1 | 2015 | 2028 |

Using excel I would just use a Vlookup or something and return the values. I have no idea how to do this in Python.

I have tried experimenting with making a duplicate dataframe and then using pd.merge but keep getting an error.

Comment: Your sample data is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name":["Foo","Foo","Foo","Bar","Bar"],
        "Year":[2012, 2017, 2022, 2015, 2024],
        "Count":[0,1,2,0,1]
    }
)
```

**solution**

```
def make_data(df_sub):   
    years = pd.Series(df_sub["Year"].sort_values().unique())
    df_sub["Prior"] = df_sub["Year"].map(dict(zip(years, years.shift()))).mask(df_sub["Count"] == 0)
    df_sub["Next"] = df_sub["Year"].map(dict(zip(years, years.shift(-1)))).fillna(df_sub["Year"]+4)
    return df_sub

df.groupby("Name").apply(make_data)
```

This gives you

```
  Name  Year  Count   Prior    Next
0  Foo  2012      0     NaN  2017.0
1  Foo  2017      1  2012.0  2022.0
2  Foo  2022      2  2017.0  2026.0
3  Bar  2015      0     NaN  2024.0
4  Bar  2024      1  2015.0  2028.0
```

The solution splits the dataframe according to `Name` values.  For each of these sub-dataframes it sorts the years, and creates maps for next and previous years.  For `Prior` column it will mask any values where `Count` column is 0.  For 'Next` column it will fill empty values with the year + 4.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the setup df code from @Riley.

We can use `numpy.where`.

```
df["Prior"] = np.where(df.groupby("Name")["Count"].shift(1).isnull(),np.nan,  df["Year"].shift(1))
df["Next"] = np.where(df.groupby("Name")["Count"].shift(-1).isnull(), df["Year"] + 4, df["Year"].shift(-1))

> df
    Name    Year    Count   Prior   Next
0   Foo     2012    0       NaN     2017.0
1   Foo     2017    1       2012.0  2022.0
2   Foo     2022    2       2017.0  2026.0
3   Bar     2015    0       NaN     2024.0
4   Bar     2024    1       2015.0  2028.0
```

Since `np.nan` is `float` type. The whole column will be float type too.